# Height and width not working on CSS Content property

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to provide height and width to CSS `content: ""` property (to draw a line) but its not working. Is this possible to apply height and width to it? Or any other work around to achieve it with `content: ""` property?

**[Fiddle with issue](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/x7wx52w8/1/)**

```
div:after {
    content: '\00af';
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

I am trying to achieve; a line before and after content spanned on entire width.

```
________like this_______
```

Comment: The `width` and `height` properties do work, try adding a `background-color` to the css. If you want to make a line it might be a better idea to use a `background-color` or a `border` instead of a character. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not use borders or other methods as compared to a character? Do you have any specific reasons for doing so?

Comment: @Harry actually i am trying to achieve something like  `________content_______` a line after some text and a line before. Spanned across full width.

Comment: @AamirShahzad: Would something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/x7wx52w8/3/) be inline with what you need?

Comment: @Harry thanks for this solution. Actually I wanted to achieve it without border or background property just with `content:''`but that seems not possible. I will shift to your solution.

Comment: @AamirShahzad: You are welcome mate. I will add it as an answer shortly but would recommend you to leave the question open (as in not accept it) as others could come up with better solutions.

Comment: Your code does set the width and height, as you can see by adding e.g. `outline: solid red` to the style. But you expect setting them do something completely different from what it really means and causes. You should post a question that describes the desired goal, rather than some assumed technique, though you should explain what you have tried. You *cannot* copy character content with CSS. But you can e.g. set a repeating background, or bottom border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to achieve the required effect is by adding a pseudo-element (`div:after` in this case) with a `border-bottom` and then position the pseudo-element and the `span` containing the text in such a way that the `span`'s border (white or the same as the background color) overlaps with the border of the pseudo-element. The `span` text is center aligned so as to give the effect that there is a line before and after it whereas actually the line is there for the full `div` but just that the part under the text is made hidden.

**Note:** I have not answered the original question because that is already covered in Tim and chipChocolate.py's answers. In essence, when you create the line using the content tag, you need to consider the line as a text and use the `font-*` properties to increase its size.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* just for demo */
}
.small{
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 2px; /* the more the padding the more the space between text and line */
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
div:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: -2px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Lengthy Text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Very Lengthy Text</span>
</div>

<div class="small">
  <span>Smaller Font</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `font-size` instead.

```css
div:after {
  content: '\00af';
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: A reason would be helpful.

Comment: Very strange that there was a down vote on this given that it answered the original question correctly.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py i didn't do it. I have given +1 for all answers as they were correct. And accepted the one most closest to my requirements.

Comment: @AamirShahzad - No worries. :) I know you didn't do it, it's obvious that it was one of my _haters_. Also, the accepted answer explains it better and I would accept that answer if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

```
div:after {
    content: '';
    background:black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 1px;
    font-size:50px;
    display: block;
}
```

---

`content: '';` places content after the div. Set it to empty.

Now we can use the box that `div:after` will generate as the bar itself, rather than use a text character.

---

Now set the `background: black;` to make the bar black.

Then adjust your `height` and `width` to how tall and wide you want your bar to be.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Content" tag renders a line, yes? Well, what's happening there is that your div **is** becoming 500px wide as requested, but it's not showing because your CSS is rendering what is essentially a character, that isn't affected by width and height properties.

If you want to change the look of this line, you've got to treat it as a character. So play with **font-size** or **font-weight** instead of height and width.